# Eclipse Invalid arguments error when using gstreamer

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, gstreamer, invalid-argument

Ok, so I want to use gstreamer library.

### 1. Situation

I have some code:

```
#include <gst/gstpipeline.h>
#include <gst/gst.h>
...
GstElement* pipe = gst_pipeline_new("PipeName");
```

Where `gst_pipeline_new` is declared in gstpipeline.h:

```
GstElement* gst_pipeline_new (const gchar* name) G_GNUC_MALLOC;
```

where non obvious "things" :) are defined somewhere in the system:

```
typedef struct _GstElement GstElement;             // gstelement.h
typedef char   gchar;                              // gtypes.h
#define G_GNUC_MALLOC  __attribute__((__malloc__)) // gmacros.h
```

### 2. Problem

Since I use make for building I have no errors during compilation and linking. Program itself runs OK as well. However...
In Eclipse IDE I have the following error:

```
Description Resource Path Location Type
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
_GstElement * gst_pipeline_new(const ? *)
' file.cc /path/to/file line 106 Semantic Error
```

I added all include directories which are specified in Makefile to eclipse project configuration (Project->Properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols->Includes->C++). Of course it's a C++ project.

### 3. Question

How to get rid of that Eclipse error? I have no clue how to do this... And it drives me mad since now I use some legacy code and I have around 100 errors like this one.

So far I've tried:

- casting either by `reinterpret_cast<>()` or C-like casting to `const gchar*`
- adding `typedef char gchar` at the beginning of the file - before any other include!
- including `gtypes.h` (`gchar` is defined there) - also before any other include
- redeclaring `_GstElement gst_pipeline_new(const gchar* name)'

Nither of those helped...

To me it looks like Eclipse does not see the `gchar` type since it says that the candidate is `_GstElement * gst_pipeline_new(const ? *)` Where `?` substitutes the real type. But I have no idea how to make (or event force :)) Eclipse to see it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As g-maulik suggested, It seems that it was really an indexer problem. After increasing the indexer cache limits everything works fine.

Go to Window->Preferences->C/C++->Indexer tab cache limits and increase (might be machine dependent):

```
Index Database cache:
Limit relative to the maximum heap size: 15%
Absolute limit: 128 MB

Header file cache:
Absolute Limit: 128 MB
```

Answer (score 2):

Most probably eclipse just doesn't know about your include paths (for this specific library) and complains about the unindexed types and declarations.

You can add them under 'Project->Properties->C++ General->Paths and Symbols'

If this doesn't help, you can also switch off semantic error checking (see Code Analysis), either in whole or for particular error types.

Comment: The problem is that I've already done that and errors still remain... I even include `gtypes.h` - the file which contains `gchar` definition and it doesn't help.

Comment: Sometimes the indexer doesn't get things correctly. You could try reindexing the project, but if that doesn't help I would simply ignore this 'error' (as it's not a real one as you mentioned), **in particular** I wouldn't start to change already compiling and running code to get rid of it.